# Stop MS Office ads on Samsung S5 (Neo)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, ads, ms-office

Today, my Samsung S5 suggested that I might want to try MS Excel:

[image: Excel testen]

A few days ago, it did the same with MS Word. Back then, I just dismissed the message and thought that I'd be done with it, but now this is getting annoying.

How do I turn off these ads? Where is the *"Yes, I know that MS Office is pre-installed and I'm quite happy about it and I'll surely use it when I need it, so stop bugging me"* button?

Comment: Not a solution, but if you rarely use it, maybe a work-around: Have you tried disabling those apps in *Settings › Apps › All?*

Comment: @Izzy: They are useful apps, I'd actually like to use them without having to re-enable them.

Comment: OK, that's an argument. Is the device rooted? You also could try "hibernating" them with *Greenify.* That way they would stay available (icons visible) and working while in foreground, while being "frozen" when not started or in background.

Comment: A simple way: Find out which app (MS Office or whatever) is showing that notification.. Open that app's 'App Info' from Settings->Apps->All and **uncheck the `Show Notifications`** checkbox. No more notifs!

Comment: @GokulNC: Won't this disable all (= including useful) notifications from that app? Or are you sure that this app never shows useful notifications?

Comment: @Heinzi Ofcourse it does disables all notifications, but I don't think MS Office ever shows an useful notification, atleast for me (I've been using MS Office for a few months & no notif ever came for me)

Answer (score 1):

Settings->Apps->All and uncheck the Show Notifications

Comment: Won't this disable all (= including useful) notifications from that app? Or are you sure that this app never shows useful notifications?

Comment: It's Microsoft,  the answer is obviously no